# Java Swing JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am building a simple tetris game where I have 3 buttons in my initial JPanel. When I press the Start Game Button, the game starts in the background but my game screen does not show up.

My Tetris class extends JFrame and I have two panels. One for 3buttons and one for the actual game. When I press the start game button, it should remove buttons and show the game JPanel.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  System.out.println("Start button pressed");
                  Tetris.this.startGame();
              }
            });
```

Here is the code for startGame(); board object also extends JPanel

```
    public void startGame(){
            remove(panel);

        board = new Board();

        board.repaint();
        tempBoard = new Board();

        board.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
                if(keyCode == leftKey && canMoveLeft()){
                    moveLeft();
                }
                if(keyCode == rightKey && canMoveRight()){
                    moveRight();
                }
                if(keyCode == downKey && canMoveDown()){
                    sleepTime = 50;
                }
            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
                if(keyCode == downKey && canMoveDown()){
                    sleepTime = 300;
                }
            }
        });
        board.setFocusable(true);

        add(board,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);

        updateGame();
```

Comment: I recommend you use javafx

Comment: Might be your `updateGame();` call, if that does nothing in the UI, I would recommend starting that call in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Container.remove(panel)

This is what you're looking for
Also, tempBoard doesnt seem to do anything.